# GitHub Actions not creating output files from python script

Tags: python, github, github-actions, filepath

Here's my github repo: https://github.com/JayThibs/github-actions-ml-template

My yaml file runs the following:

```
  pip3 install -r requirements.txt
  python training/train.py
  
  echo "## MODEL METRICS" >> report.md
  cat training/outputs/metrics.txt >> report.md
  
  echo "## Data viz" >> report.md
  cml-publish training/outputs/feature_importance.png --md >> report.md
  cml-publish training/outputs/residuals.png --md >> report.md
  
  cml-send-comment report.md
```

which is fine, but the issue is that when it runs `python training/train.py`, the outputs from that file are not found in the repository. Here's one of the things that it should be outputting to `training/outputs/`:

```
# Create directory for outputs
if not os.path.exists("./training/outputs/"):
        os.makedirs("./training/outputs/")

# Write scores to a file
with open("./training/outputs/metrics.txt", 'w') as outfile:
        outfile.write("Training variance explained: %2.1f%%\n" % train_score)
        outfile.write("Test variance explained: %2.1f%%\n" % test_score)
```

It works if I run it locally (that's why two of the files are in output; I deleted one to test Actions), but no outputs are saved with Actions.

If I replace the path with:

```
with open("metrics.txt", 'w') as outfile:
```

It saves the files in the directory root. So, I'm not sure what's going wrong when I change paths.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Did the script create the `outputs` folder? It could be related to permission to perform some operation. If the folder is not created by the workflow, try using `sudo python training/train.py`.

Comment: It was not creating the `outputs` folder, so I ran the code locally to see if I needed to create the folder first. I just tried `sudo python training/train.py` and it's saying `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'` for the first line in `train.py` even though pandas was installed. `sudo` is running the code in another env?

Comment: It runs if I do `sudo pip3 install -r requirements.txt`, though the files are still not in `outputs`.

Comment: It's possible that using `sudo` change the workflow default behaviour. I don't know exactly how, I'll have to investigate to understand better... Did you try creating the `outputs` folder through shell command instead, to see if it performs the full operation as expected?